# Login Screen Keyboard Layout says German, but is actually English

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, login-screen, unity-greeter

On an Ubuntu 16.04 server, the login screen says the keyboard layout is set to German:

[image]

However, when typing my password, I can clearly see this to be false. It appears to actually use English kbd layout (z- and y-keys are switched). When I  select English (US) layout instead, I am actually getting the German one.

How can I correct this issue?